# It is not possible to know the output of execute() (CakePHP3.x)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I update one record in a DB:

```
$res = $query->update()
        ->set(['activation' => true])
        ->where(['sha1' => $hash])
        ->execute();
```

The request itself is executed correctly (This is visible when you change the database itself.).

And further I try to receive result of a method execute():

```
debug($res->fetchAll('assoc'));
```

But gives the error: Database Error.

If I do not use ->fetchAll('assoc') - everything works, but I do not know if the request was fulfilled correctly or not.

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I know the result of executing the execute () method?

Comment: I'd say that you first need to define what "_correctly_" means in that context. Does it mean the query ran without errors? Does it mean at least _n_ rows were affected? Maybe something different?

Comment: @ndm The request itself is executed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, in order to find out whether a query was performed to update the data in the database, you need:

```
// Create the request object
$query = $this->Users->query();

// Prepare the terms of the request
$query->update()
   ->set(['activation' => true])
   ->where(['sha1' => $hash]);

// We try to execute the query and immediately check the result
if($query->execute()->rowCount() === 1){
    // Query succeeded
} else {
    // Request failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `->rowCount()` on the result to see if it affected a number of rows, or `->errorInfo()` on the result to get any associated errors. As this isn't a `SELECT` query, there isn't any resultSet to "fetch", so calling `->fetchAll()` is indeed the wrong method here.

Comment: But how do I know if the request was successful?

Comment: And, I understood, I will mark your answer as correct, and I'll write the code below. Thank you! :)